# Como definir os valores possíveis de uma string em uma iterface a partir de um objeto?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Tenho essa classe `Item`:

```
class Item {
  nome: string;
  idade: number;
}
```

E essa interface `ConfItem`:

```
interface ConfItem<TypeItem> {
  titulo: string;
}
```

Como faço para o título em `ConfItem` aceite somente como valor string uma das `keys` de `Item` que é recebido pelo `TypeItem`?

Preciso de algo tipo assim:

```
interface ConfItem<TypeItem> {
  titulo: 'nome' | 'idade' 
}
```

Mas tem que se dinâmico, pois `ConfItem` vai ser genérico, e portanto pode receber qualquer `TypeItem`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode usar o `keyof`, que retorna um *union type* de strings contendo todas as chaves do objeto.

Então você teria algo como:

```
interface ConfItem<TypeItem> {
  titulo: keyof TypeItem 
}
```

<sup>Consulte o exemplo acima no [TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?strictPropertyInitialization=false&ssl=1&ssc=39&pln=1&pc=28#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMIHsQwJKQLYA8AKgJ4AOEuEeAfMgN4BQyyYwYArgDboBcyAawgl0MZKQpU8yRgF9GjBFzgBnFcikNmyEOjwR+KsFFABzANzbgAEzjWDOjngBG0S-MZhyKALIkJKAC8aJg4+ARSNJaKmEbIEAAecHhkXBAAjPx+AcjBTCxsnDz8AES6+iXIAPRVyADyANJyCgixYPFJKWkATFn+3rlaBezcfMglNnYQlTX1TR6tIHGJyakQAMx9OXnahaOlAI4ccFxH0DO1OQDkJUcnZ1AlV8jA6rrtqirApiBwzmmsdCsAY3crTZAAH3Gk3sTwAdHIgA).</sup>